# Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '10s'

Tags: java, string, string.format

I'm no doubt missing something really obvious here but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. The mistake is coming from here:

```
package B00166353_Grades;

public class Student{
    String name,banner;

    public Student(String name,String banner){
        this.name=name;
        this.banner=banner;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String productDetails=new String();
        productDetails+=String.format("%-20s%10.2s%10s",this.name,this.banner);
        return productDetails;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error is some where else. where is your main method?

Comment: No, it's right there in `toString()`. Only two parameters are passed...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your format string `"%-20s%10.2s%10s"` takes three parameters:

1. `%-20s`
2. `%10.2s`
3. `%10s`

but only supply two parameters:

1. `this.name`
2. `this.banner`

The error message states that the third parameter (for `%10s`) is missing.

So either adjust your format string or add the third parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You have:

```
productDetails+=String.format("%-20s%10.2s%10s",this.name,this.banner);
```

Since you have three `%s` in your `String`, `format()` expects three paramteres, but you only pass `this.name` and `this.banner`.

Also, since you're inside of `Student`, you do **not** need to use `this`.  You can simply reference them by `name` and `banner`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an argument to the method `format`, because your formatted string awaits for 3 arguments, not two.

Answer (score 0):

```
productDetails+=String.format("%-20s%10.2s%10s",this.name,this.banner);
```

I think that you must pass another argument, because you pass only name and banner but in the string you have 3 times %.. try the same with only %-20s%10.2s